# Scala Dataframe null check for columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

```
val new_df = df.filter($"type_interne" !== "" || $"type_interne" !== "null")
```

Give me error value `||` is not member of string

When i use `===` works well for filter

```
val new_df = df.filter($"type_interne" === "" || $"type_interne" === "null")
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem seems to be the operator precedence, try to use braces:

```
 val new_df = df.filter(($"type_interne" !== "") || ($"type_interne" !== null))
```

you can also write it like this:

```
val new_df = df.filter(($"type_interne" !== "") or $"type_interne".isNotNull)
```

Comment: Use =!= for latest version.

Answer (score 7):

Though Raphael's answer was fully correct at the time of writing, spark evolving...
Operator `!==` is deprecated since version 2.0, but you can use `=!=` which solves precedence problem above without using parenthesis. See corresponding comments in source code:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala#L319-L320

*Detailed answer:*
I'd like also to note something which was not obvious for me in the beginning.
There are notions of DataFrame (DF) and DataSet (DS), which also divide their usage in above context into:
1) strings which interpreted by catalyst (error are caught up only in run time) - both DF and DS
    case class NullStrings(n: Int, s: String)

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    (1, "abc"),
    (2, "ABC"),
    (3, null),
    (4, ""))
).toDF("n", "s")

df.filter("s is not null and s != ''").show()

+---+---+
|  n|  s|
+---+---+
|  1|abc|
|  2|ABC|
+---+---+
```

2) dataframe syntax using `Column` notion (`$` with `spark.implicits._` import) partially compile checked:

```
df.filter($"s" =!= "" || $"s" =!= null).show()
```

but in fact `=!=` ignores nulls (see `<=>` for null-safe comparison), hence below is equal to

```
df.filter($"s" =!= "").show()

+---+---+
|  n|  s|
+---+---+
|  1|abc|
|  2|ABC|
+---+---+
```

3) dataset

```
val ds = df.as[NullStrings]

ds.filter(r => r.s != null && r.s.nonEmpty).show()
+---+---+
|  n|  s|
+---+---+
|  1|abc|
|  2|ABC|
+---+---+
```

*Beware* if you use `Option` in case class, you have to deal with it, not simple string.

```
case class NullStringsOption(n: Int, s: Option[String])

val ds1 = df.as[NullStringsOption]

ds1.filter(_.s.exists(_.nonEmpty)).show()
```