# Join two Spark Dataframes on Multiple Fields

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, join

I am trying to join two dataframes in Spark on multiple fields. I tried this:

```
df1.
   join(df2, df1$col1 == df2$col2 && df1$col3 == df2$col4)
```

But this does not work (there are a range of errors, I can list if needed).

Is there a better way to write this? I need to do this in Spark, not pySpark, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala Dataframe null check for columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500732/scala-dataframe-null-check-for-columns)

Answer (score 3):

This procedure in pyspark also worked for me. Hope this is helpful!

```
df1.join(df2, \
    (df1["col1"]==df2["col2"]) & \
    (df1["col3"]==df2["col4"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark I have to take wrap condition into set of braces, as there is something wrong with operation priorities.

Maybe you have the same issue:

```
df1.
   join(df2, (df1$col1 == df2$col2) && (df1$col3 == df2$col4))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an dataframe as df1 and df2 you need to do as

```
df1.join(df2, (df1("col1") === df2("col2")) && (df1("col3") === df2("col4")))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me

```
result=(
        df1
        .join(
            df2,
            (df1.col1 == df2.col1) & 
            (df1.col2 == df2.col2) & 
            (df1.col3 == df2.col3),
            how="left"
        )
```